# Change Bootstrap Header Link color on hover

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried all my efforts to solve this simple problem but I can't figure out why it doesn't work.
The code for header is

```
/*-- header --*/
.header{
    padding: 1em 0;
    background: url(../images/header-bg.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    background-size: 27% 100%;
    margin-top:0px;
}
.logo{
    float:left;
    margin-top:0.5em;
}
span.menu{
    display:none;
}
.top-nav{
    float:right;
}
.top-nav ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.top-nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}
.top-nav ul li a{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#2C3E50;
    margin:1em 1.3em;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.top-nav ul li a:hover,.top-nav ul li.active a{
    color:#f22b2b;
}



 <style>
        #navtopbar {
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
        }
</style>

<div class="nav navbar-fixed-top" id="navtopbar">
     <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="top-nav">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <span class="menu"> </span>
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                            <ul>
                                <li id="linkcolor" class="active"><a href="~/index/index">Home</a></li>
                                <li id="linkcolor"><a href="~/Index/AboutUs">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="~/Doctor/Index">Doctors</a></li>
                                <li><a href="~/Hospitals/Index">Hospitals</a></li>
                                <li><a href="~/Clinics/Index">Clinics</a></li>
                                <li><a href="~/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>

                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

The color it displays on active and on hover is blue by default. I want to change it to red. In css it is

```
.top-nav ul li a:hover,.top-nav ul li.active a{
    color:#f22b2b;
```

But still it shows blue. So i try to overwrite the css by inline styling.

I have tried `.nav > li > a {color: red}` or `.navbar-collapse > ul > li > a {color: red}` or `.nav > li {color:red}` or `.nav > li > a:hover{color:red;}` or `ul.nav a:hover, ul.nav a:focus, ul.nav a:active { color:red; }`
No one is working for me. Please suggest where am I doing the mistake?

PS: screen shot also attached[image]

Comment: This blue color on your screenshot is not default Bootstrap.

Comment: @makshh okay my mistake all i want, change this blue to red.

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: you need to put your css after bootstrap to overwrite the existing style.

Comment: But you didn't show your all CSS code where this blue is used.

Comment: I have added the css. Please review it @makshh

Comment: @AhsN I have created a demo on on JSFiddle. it is working fine but not in my project. 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lr3zx3yr/

Comment: I changed the last CSS to `color:#f22b2b !important;` adding the `!important` part. Can you please try it in your project and let me know?

Comment: @AhsN no still not working :(

Comment: Anyway I can access it to help out?

Comment: your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ZcLSE/1481/

Comment: @this.girish this fiddle is not working

Comment: I copied your code and I see red link.

Comment: @makshh As i mentioned it is working fine on fiddle but not in my project. That's why i tried to add inline styling as well to solve this problem. but failed.

Comment: So there is nothing we can do about it without seeing your project.

Comment: why your super-code is not working, it;s working everywhere on earth.

Comment: Bad day for me. I am really confused. I have now remove hierarchy from external style sheet still it shows blue.

Comment: @this.girish seriously I wonder why this happening. I just removed the hierarchy from external style sheet as well but still it shows blue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below hierarchy

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color:red;
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/TG6OQhgrRpIJxVCW1dAW?p=preview)**

Comment: I am sorry to say but this one is also not working for me.

Comment: He doesn't use .navbar-default nor .navbar-nav... so this won't work

Comment: can you create a demo @RjSunny

Comment: I have also added the CSS and create a demo. please review the comments

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
.navbar-collapse ul li a:hover, .navbar-collapse ul li a:active { color:red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to target the li when you need to be targeting the a anchor.

Look at the example here:

```
.navbar-default .nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-default .nav > li > a.active {
    color: #fe0000;
}
```

if you make changes to the above to suit your code you will find that it will change the color on hover, focus and active for you.

Hope that helps